# RestEasy not working in JBoss 7.2

Tags: java, jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy

I am using JBoss 7.2 and I have a empty web.xml in my application as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```

I used the dependency:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The simple application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}

@Path("/v1")
public class RestfulService {

    @POST
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/test")
    public String testAPI() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("status", "Success");
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
}
```

But I get `HTTP 404` when trying `localhost:8080/testapplication/rest/v1/test`. Is there anything I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the `web.xml` as:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
         <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.technology.apiinterface.restful.service.JaxRsActivator</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>

            <context-param>
                <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
                <param-value>/rest</param-value>
            </context-param>
</web-app>
```

And changed **JaxRsActivator** class:

```
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public JaxRsActivator() {
        singletons.add(new RestfulService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Now when trying `localhost:8080/testapplication/rest/v1/test`, I get following exception:

```
Allocate exception for servlet Resteasy: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.technology.apiinterface.restful.service.JaxRsActivator cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Application
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:295) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:236) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:112) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:950) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:151) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
```

Comment: First assumption: it is NOT something mysterious. Looks like you are extending the wrong Application class.

Comment: `import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;` It is not wrong import, is it?

Comment: Hm actually no it isn't wrong. Checking against my own setup, I have no servlet, I just annotate the application class with @ApplicationPath("/REST") which is the trigger for JBoss to actually initialize the JAX-RS subsystem.

Comment: I even tried with empty `web.xml` and `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` but when deploying I get `No Servlet mappings found for JAX-RS application: com.technology.apiinterface.restful.service.JaxRsActivator either annotate it with @ApplicationPath or add a servlet-mapping in web.xml`

Comment: Yeah so something is wrong in the setup. Alas based on what you have provided here, I cannot say what. The annotation way is correct, "works on my machine" and I too run my own JBoss 7.2 build, although I upgraded RestEasy to the latest version to get rid of problems with an outdated Jackson library. You're sure no RestEasy / JAX-RS jars are deployed with your application right?

Answer (score 1):

If your `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclass is not annotated with `@ApplicationPath`, can you try with something like this in your `web.xml` ?

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.technology.apiinterface.restful.service.JaxRsActivator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

You should be able to get rid of this JaxRsActivator class and have something like this instead, if you prefer (RESTEasy should discover all JAX-RS Resources and Subresources, Providers, etc.):

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```